# HR/Talent Acquisition not responding after sending renegotiation email

Tags: job-offer, unprofessional-behavior, compensation

I have accepted an offer on Jan 10, and my last working day in my present organization is in 3 weeks.

I contacted the HR who was responsible for my case around Feb 3 on phone to discuss if I can renegotiate the compensation. He said it was not possible at that time.

After some rethinking, I sent an email asking for a discussion on compensation to him again on Feb 22 and also CC another guy to whom I talked first about the compensation before the offer letter was sent.

There is no response from their side yet, also they aren't picking calls.

Should I be worried or should I give some more time and then call someone else asking about an update ?

Comment: What part of "It's not possible" was unclear to you when they first answered you? Why exactly would they be willing to negotiate with you right now that you have already accepted their offer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @gnat that doesn't seem particularly relevant to this case

Comment: @mattfreake I think gnat is assuming OP is now trying to make sure they still have this job, since their question begins with "Should I be worried" and they're asking about an update.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clarify whether you're now just trying to confirm you still have this job or whether the update you want to ask about is still about pay?

Comment: The fact they are not responding is a terrbile sign .

Answer (score 20):

You accepted an offer and now want to renegotiate before starting the new job.  They told you no.  Now you're asking them again, and trying to bring additional people into the conversation.  Most likely they're ignoring you because its asked and answered.  If you want this job I'd be cautious about continuing down this path-  this is the kind of thing offers get revoked from.  You'll frequently get some flex in starting date if something comes up, but renegotiating salary is a lot more iffy-  they may decide you're not reliable.  Honestly if I were the hiring manager/recruiter I'd be second guessing my hiring decision, especially with you copying in random other people.

Answer (score 18):

> Should i be worried ?

Yes. That is a terrible way to start a new job. The time for negotiation was BEFORE you accepted the offer. That is what accepting means: you agreed to take the job at the compensation and conditions offered.

> or should i give some more time and then call someone else asking about an update ?

No. You should stop calling. I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, but it's not going to work

1. You will NOT get more compensation. You already agreed to the original one, and you already received a hard "no". This will not change.
2. At this point you are just antagonizing your new employer and you are behaving very unprofessionally. This will not make you look bad and make your start more difficult that it needs to be.

If you really feel you need more money, you need to find another job and don't accept until the compensation is what you need it to be.

Answer (score 8):

I am sorry, but you are potentially in a bad position.

There are 2 general rules:

1. The first rule is that after you accept an offer from a
   company, please do not call back to ask for a higher salary or
   better benefits. Most companies do not like that scenario.

   **Consequently, in this case, some times, these companies may decide to withdraw the offer, and hire someone else instead.**
2. The second rule is that :  Do not resign from your current company
   until you get the official job offer letter that you are happy with, and you are 100% ready to go.

   Now, if the new company, unfortunately, decides to withdraw your job
   offer, and hire someone else instead, here is another potential bad
   thing:  **What if your current company decides not to take you back
   as you already resigned ?**

If both of these scenarios happen at the same time, you may end up without a job at least for a little while.

---

However, I hope that you can still have a job at either of these 2 companies. Best of luck. Cheers. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Let's frame this differently.  You need to buy a new car.  You find a seller online that has what you're looking for, and the price you're willing to pay.  But the seller is 1,000 miles away from you, and you decide to go retrieve it in person.  As a show of good faith, you transmit $100 to the seller to not sell the car out from underneath you (which the seller will refund if you at least show up), and convince a relative to drive you 13 hours to inspect and possibly seal the deal.

You get on the road and get a text asking for more money.

Four hours later, you get an email still asking for more money.

Two hours later, the seller's wife calls you and badgers you about not responding to her husband's text messages and emails.

I'm noticing the tag "unprofessional behavior" beneath your question.  Maybe we need to examine what that means.

Comment: the unprofessional behavior tag is extremely appropriate, but not for the reason the question asker thought.

Comment: @TigerGuy Spot on!